# Trinity College, Cambridge, circa 1896 maths scholarship papers

Tags: books, ho.history-overview

I've been searching around looking for the (maths component) of the scholarship papers to Trinity College (Cambridge) from around 1890. Can anyone provide a link to a pdf scan of these papers?

Was the scholarship paper some kind of combined paper or did it cover maths only? Anyway I'd like to have a look at the breadth of topics covered and the types of questions.

Comment: Is it a coincidence that G. H. Hardy was a student at Trinity College starting in 1896?

Comment: that's in fact not coincidential to my question .

Comment: Have to checked to see whether Trinity has them archived?

Comment: This should probably be asked on [hsm.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question.  There are many questions that were included in the college entrance and scholarship papers to be found in for example Routh's Dynamics of a Particle and various other text books of the time.

Still I'd love to see a scan of a few complete papers from this period circa 1890.

Cheers,
Aelered